# Ignore points with y=0

Tags: gnuplot

I am plotting a graph and I would like to omit all points that have y=0. I don't know a priori at which lines these results appear, so I can't tell gnuplot to use just some lines.

Is that possible or do I have to edit my data set (and replace y=0 for somewhere outside my range)?

Comment: First you say "omit all points", but then you say "use just some lines". Are you saying you want to leave out the lines that cross the y-axis within the range of your data set?

Comment: @JAB The first thought (and if I had a small data set) was to manually tell gnuplot which lines to use, but this is impracticable in my case. Yes, what I want is to leave out the lines the cross the y-axis

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can do this pretty easily:

```
plot "mydataset.dat" u 1:($2 == 0 ? NaN : $2)
```

Here we use the gnuplot ternary operator to replace values of `0` with `NaN`.  Gnuplot silently ignores `NaN`, so that should work just fine.

Comment: Perfect, that's exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 18):

The elegant way to do that is using:

`set datafile missing`

For example, you can do:

`set datafile missing '0'`

and gnuplot will skip the entries with the 0 symbol. You can use strings as well as NaN or 0.000.

Comment: what if there was a point with x = 0? Wouldn't that skip it as well?

Comment: Yes, that was an example where you want to skip entries with 0. That it is a custom value which tells gnuplot which value to skip.

Comment: Thank you!    In my case, the DHT-22 wire is loose so set datafile missing "0.00" allowed it to just skip the false readings.

Comment: Upvoted both answers. Your solution is global (and that was the question), but the ternary operator solution is very good as it gives granularity if we have several data to plot on Y.