# ploting gnuplot and divide operation by zero

Tags: bash, gnuplot

I am using gnuplot to build a graph but some of my lines are zero and I am making a math with two columns. Divide any number by zero is throwing a error when I try to plot my file.

```
set output "iostat-iops.png"
set title "IOPs - KBytes per IO"
set xdata time
set timefmt "%H:%M:%S"
set format x "%H:%M"
plot "iostat-x.dat.1" using 2:($9/$7) title "rkb/s" with linespoints, \
"iostat-x.dat.1" using 2:($10/$8) title "wkb/s" with linesponints
```

In my example I have the column 7 with zero sometimes. Is there a way to make a IF on it?

Comment: Check this out, I think here's solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11865349/ignore-points-with-y-0

Comment: In your case, you should change `using 2:($9/$7)` to `using 2:($7 == 0 ? NaN : $9 / $7)` to skip data where column 7 is 0.